# Excel we need string data skip Blank and Sort

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Right now we're facing some challenge please see the excel below :

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IStyp.png)

we need string the data from those cells and skip blank

Comment: What version of Excel do you have? In Office 365 there's `FILTER` and `SORT`

Comment: [This](https://www.get-digital-help.com/create-a-unique-distinct-sorted-list-containing-both-numbers-text-removing-blanks-in-excel/) might be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do a textjoin and a mid. The textjoin allows for empty values to be ignored (2nd argument). If your data is in area B4:J6, then the formula in K4 would be (for "latest" excel):

```
=MID(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,$B4:$J4),COLUMN()-10,1)
```

Drag the formula to the right and down (or use fill right (ctrl-R) and fill down (ctrl-D). (replace the column()-10 with what ever column you're using, in my example K is column 10)

Edit: Sorry, didn't at first notice the excel-2010 tag. This formula should do the same trick:

```
=MID(CONCATENATE($B4:$J4),COLUMN()-10,1)
```

Comment: One of the OP tags is exel-2010...?

Comment: Didn't notice the excel-2010 at first. I've added excel-2010 option to my answer